# Java linked list set method

Tags: java, sorting, linked-list

I have to convert my ArrayList code to Linked list without using import.java.util.LinkedList.

My previous code has 4 ArrayList (name, price, quantity, priority)

I have to sort arraylist depends on ArrayList prioirty.

So I did like this.

```
public void sortPriority() {
    for (int i=0; i<name.length(); i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<priority.size()-i-1; j++) {
            if (priority.get(j).compareTo(priority.get(j+1)) > 0) {
                int temp1 = priority.get(j);
                priority.set(j,priority.get(j+1));
                priority.set(j+1, temp1);
                String temp2 = name.get(j);
                name.set(j,name.get(j+1));
                name.set(j+1, temp2);
                double temp3 = price.get(j);
                price.set(j,price.get(j+1));
                price.set(j+1, temp3);
                int temp4 = quantity.get(j);
                quantity.set(j,quantity.get(j+1));
                quantity.set(j+1, temp4);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I changed my name ArrayList to Linked List.

Since I cannot import java.util.LinkedList, I put my own code in other class called StringLinkedList.

```
abstract class StringLinkedList implements LinkList {

private ListNode head;

public StringLinkedList() {
    head = null;
}
public void showList() {
    ListNode position = head;
    while (position != null) {
        System.out.println(position.getData());
        position = position.getLink();
    }
}
public int length() {
    int count = 0;
    ListNode position = head;
    while (position != null) {
        count++;
        position = position.getLink();
    }
    return count;
}

public void addNodeToStart(String addData) {
    head = new ListNode(addData, head);
}
public void deleteHeadNode() {
    if (head != null) {
        head = head.getLink();
    } else {
        System.out.println("Deleting from an empty list.");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

public boolean onList(String target) {
    return find(target) != null;
}
private ListNode find(String target) {
    boolean found = false;
    ListNode position = head;
    while ((position != null) && !found) {
        String dataAtPosition = position.getData();
        if (dataAtPosition.equals(target)) {
            found = true;
        } else {
            position = position.getLink();
        }
    }
    return position;
}

public String get(int i) {
    assert (i>=0);
    ListNode current = this.head;
    while (i > 0) {
        i--;
        current = current.link;
        if (current == null) {
            return null;
        }
    }
    return current.data;
}

public String set (int index, String element) {
    ListNode current = this.head;
    ListNode e = current;
    String oldVal = e.element;
    e.element = element;
    return oldVal;
}
}
```

Every other methods works fine besides my set().

What should I change?

Comment: *"I have to convert my ArrayList code to Linked list without using import.java.util.LinkedList."* You can always use the fully qualified name.

Comment: @arshajii It's homework. He can't.

Comment: @arshajii - I think OP means that the assignment is to come up with an independent implementation of a linked list.

Comment: I know, it was a joke.

Comment: First of all, could you please explain why you cannot import LinkedList and what error you get with `set()`? You cannot import LinkedList but you certainly do so, when you create StringLinkedList which extends LinkedList.

Comment: @user2435872 - OP is implementing some _interface_ named `LinkedList`. It can't be `java.util.LinkedList` because that's a class, not an interface. This is clearly some sort of school assignment.

Comment: @arshajii Good, but a bit subtle. 7/10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `set()` method ignores the `index` parameter that is passed in. As written it just modifies the item at the head of the list.

You will have to implement `set()` similarily to `get()` - find the item with the specified index, then set that item's element.

Comment: I figure it out.  Thanks for your helping.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move `current` forward `index` times before setting the value. Look at how you are doing it in `get` and use similar logic.